# 2 strings replace javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a beginner, how do I combine them:

```
var mystring = "my.email@computer.com";
document.write(mystring.replace(/@/, "&&"));
```

prints `my.email&&computer.com`

```
var mystring = "my.email@computer.com";
document.write(mystring.replace(/\./, "##"));
```

prints `my##email@computer.com`

I have two questions:
How do I make this regex (mystring.replace(/./, "##") to after `@` change the `dot` to `##`  and how can I combine those two lines into one, and final read is:`my.email&&computer##com`

Comment: `mystring.replace(/@/, "&&").replace(/\./, "##")`   :)

Comment: hold on, you expect result is `my.email&&computer##com` instead of `my##email&&computer##com` ?

Comment: @Rain Diao yes, need this `my.email&&computer##com`

Comment: See the single replace solution too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

input  : `my.first.last.email@example.computer.com`

result : `my.first.last.email&&example##computer##com`

Solution 1:

```
var mystring = "my.first.last.email@example.computer.com";
//replace '.' after '@' with '##', then replace '@' with '&&'.
var result = mystring.replace(/(?!.*@)\./g, "##").replace(/@/, "&&");
document.write(result);
```

Solution 2 (configurable):

```
var mystring = "my.email@computer.com";

var replacements = {
                    '@' : '&&',
                    '.' : '##'
                   };

var str =  "my.first.last.email@example.computer.com";

//match latter part of the string
var result = str.replace(/@\w+(\.\w+)+/g, function(at_and_after) {
    //replace all '.' and '@' in that part.
    return at_and_after.replace(/@|\./g, function(m) { return replacements[m]});
});
document.write(result);  //console.log(result) or alert(result) is a better way for demo
```

Comment: thanks but it prints `my##email&&computer.com`, I'd like it to print `my.email&&computer##com`

Comment: thanks again, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;  on line 15

Comment: Many thanks @Rain Diao, it prints `my##email&&computer##com`, I guess the regex needs to be like,  do nothing before `@`, after `@` then replace `.`

Comment: he used `/g` , it means all `.` will be replaced with `##`

Comment: yes, but remove `/g`, it doesnt replace the last `.`, just needed to replace the last `.`

Comment: hold on, i'm updating my answer.

Comment: THanks alot, I just don't know how to make the regex to work like once match @ change `.` after

Comment: yes! Ticked this one for the right answer, BTW, how to return results from the second one? `document.write(str.replace())`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
var mystring = "my.email@computer.com";
document.write(mystring.replace(/(.*@.*)\./, "$1##").replace(/@/, "&&"));
```

Comment: Updated answer to skip replacing dot before @.

Comment: @olo Remember, this only replaces a single occurrence of @ and dot.

Answer (score 1):

You could use split to split the string at /@/ and apply the second regexp to the second part of the string, then join the results back together with &&.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var mystring = "my.email@computer.com";
document.write(mystring.replace(/(.*?)(@)(.*?)(\.)(.*)/, "$1&&$3##$5"));
```

Result:

```
my.email&&computer##com
```

See it here working: http://jsfiddle.net/gnB85/

Comment: @olo - I didn't noticed that you wanted to replace the "@" by two "&" ... It's fixed now. You get "&&" instead of "@" in a single regex replace

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var mystring = "my.email@computer.com"
document.write(mystring.replace(/\.(?!\w+@)/, '##').replace(/@/, '&&'));
```